# Xcode Storyboard constraint changing image size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, constraints

I have an image on my storyboard. When I select it and try to add the top constraint it will resize the image and make it bigger. I cannot figure out what it is doing that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UIImageView` has no intrinsic size, until you've assigned its image property.

At that point, if **you** have not given it any other constraints to control its width and height, it will use the *image size* as its intrinsic size.